Laravel/Inertia/Breeze/Vue application loads javascript files only on second click to link in production mode
I have a Laravel/Inertia/Breeze/vue/vite application with links to several pages/indexes. When I run in development mode it all works fine and the pages display with no problem.
When i deploy to production, some pages only get displayed on the second click to the link. Chrome shows 404 on first click (and Firefox sometimes shows chunkXXXX.js was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type) but if I click the link again, then it works fine.
It seems so type of timing issue serving up the pages.
BTW I have another app which does not use Breeze and it does not have the problem.
Not sure if it is related to npm build and the vite config files which are different for each app.
Has anyone seen this behavior? I will appreciate any insight or suggestions.
I tried changing vite for the other app but the npm build did not work.

check your production ssl certs. Literally just went through this...

Thanks for the suggestion, Could you elaborate? But I don't think it is related to ssl because I am using only HTTP (the app is used only in my home network).
